# How do I tell Chrome to stop auto completing to a website?

Tags: google-chrome

When I type in the omnibar at the top

```
goo
```

it autocompetes to

```
google.com.au
```

rather than

```
google.com
```

This is driving me crazy. How do I blacklist a site so autocomplete doesn't show it? Or, how do I get it to autocomplete again to `google.com`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove these items from the autocomplete list:

1. Start typing the URL you want to remove
2. Use the up/down arrow keys to highlight it
3. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> to remove this from your autocomplete list

Comment: I officially like you more than Trump.