# Google Search Autofill/complete Disable

Tags: google-chrome, search, autocomplete

Similar question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/562477/how-can-i-disable-chromes-address-bar-search-autocomplete)

When typing in Google Search Bar (Chrome or google.com) the search bar will autocomplete based on previous searches (example below). I would like to disable this.

For example:

1. I search something like "numpy indexing with list"
2. I try another similar search of "numpy index" (intentionally leaving out "ing with list"), but Google will autofill this to be "numpy indexing with list".

This causes me to repeat the first search, go back a page, retype my second search, then press backspace to remove the autocompleted/filled characters from the first step. Seems small, but I run into this issue all the time it's quite an annoying user experience. Also, to be clear, I don't mind suggestions popping up below my search, I just want to disable Google coercing my search into something I've previously typed. I want exactly what I type to be my search, nothing more, nothing less.

Things I've tried to fix this:

1. In Chrome, going to Settings > Advanced Settings > Privacy, and deselecting the "Use a prediction service to help complete searches and URLs typed in the address bar" checkbox (I believe this has been deprecated)
2. In Chrome, going to Settings > Sync and Google Services > Other Google Services, and disabling Autocomplete searches and URLs
3. Clearing cookies

Thanks for any help!