# How do I disable Google Chrome's autocomplete?

Tags: google-chrome

Something I find extremely annoying with Google Chrome is the fact that it will autocomplete my searches in the Omnibox, adding or extending words.

For example, if I type "youtube down" it automatically gets extended to "youtube downloader", which is a totally different query.

Is there anyway to disable this feature? It would be preferable to keep the suggestions, but just have them not automatically selected when typing.

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like [this](http://superuser.com/questions/319958/how-to-turn-off-chromes-annoying-auto-fill/543412#543412) was the right answer. ["There will never be an option to disable autocompletion entirely."](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=91378#c1)

Answer (score 2):

Turning off Predictions in the address bar:

- Clear browsing history (optional - only do this if you don't want to see matches from your browsing history).
- `Wrench icon --> Options --> Under the hood --> Privacy --> uncheck "Use a prediction service to help complete searches and URLs typed in the address bar"`

[link to google Chrome documentation](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95656)

Comment: This still doesn't turn off suggestions from your history and bookmarks. It only prevents Chrome from fetching suggestions at Google's servers.

Answer (score 1):

Install [Fauxbar](http://code.google.com/p/fauxbar/) for Chrome and be happy with it. It will add an alternative address bar to Omnibox. By entering "youtube down" in Fauxbar and pressing Enter will directly take you to [downrightnow.com](http://downrightnow.com/youtube).

Either that or replace Chrome by Firefox.

I personally don't find this very annoying, all I have to do in a situation like that is type in "youtube down" and press Backspace once, and then Enter. This takes you to the Google search result page, and you have to click the first link to get to the above mentioned website. The address bar in Firefox works the same way.